# How to do the transformation in log operator?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I just see the equations, and can not understand the math behind this equation.

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $f^Tf^+$ is independent of $i$. So we can factor it out.

So,

$$\begin{align}\log\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{L-1}\exp(f^Tf_i-f^Tf^+)\right)&=\log\left(1+\exp(-f^Tf^+)\sum_{i=1}^{L-1}\exp(f^Tf_i)\right)\\\\
&=\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\exp(f^Tf^+)}\sum_{i=1}^{L-1}\exp(f^Tf_i)\right)\\\\
&=\log\left(\frac{\exp(f^Tf^+)+\sum_{i=1}^{L-1}\exp(f^Tf_i)}{\exp(f^Tf^+)}\right)\\\\
&=-\log\left(\frac{\exp(f^Tf^+)}{\exp(f^Tf^+)+\sum_{i=1}^{L-1}\exp(f^Tf_i)}\right)\end{align}$$